# RevealJs like rotation in ImpressJs

Tags: html, css, javascript-framework, reveal.js, impress.js

Playing with impress.js

I'm trying to acheive a Reveal.js like slide transition, but using impress.js.
The basic effect did come, but i feel, the slides are taking a 'wider' turn making it look a lil slower.

*Note : In the fiddle, maximize the output section to see the said problem more clearly*

I dont know how else to put it, but if you see http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/fragments and 
http://jsfiddle.net/8ukwex3x/1/,  you will be able to make out the difference.

```
<div id = "impress">
    <div class = "step">
        Slide 1
    </div>
    <div class = "step" data-x = "500" data-z="-400" 
    data-rotate-y="90">
        Slide 2
    </div>  
</div>
```

What should I do to make it work just like Reveal.js' transition.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your fiddle is completely missing the JavaScript (where I assume you had intended to put just the standard impress.js code) and in any case, just reading from the source code I don't see how your example is in any way similar to what the reveal-js example does. So, with the risk that I might be completely off here, I have one thing that may hopefully be helpful...

The reveal.js transitions are indeed pretty slick and fast. Did you know that you can set the duration of a transition in impress.js? The attribute is data-transition-duration:

```
<div id="impress" data-transition-duration="1000">
```

[A demo slide show that uses it here.](https://github.com/henrikingo/impress.js/blob/5687a1b452292f87a7d568a10f82b9a9f99d6537/examples/classic-slides/index.html#L80)

The default is 1000 ms. A value at about 400-600 ms should give you the reveal.js experience in terms of speed.

PS: Note that in my impress.js repo, where the above link is to, you can also set a duration for each individual step/slide. For the upstream impress.js, all slides have the same duration, set in the root div element.